# How to get current kudu master or tserver flag value?

Tags: apache-kudu

Master and tserver flags can be accessed from kudu web interfaces (by defult http://127.0.0.1:8051/varz and http://127.0.0.1:8050/varz).

But I couldn't find a way to get it from command line.

For example, how to get tserver_master_addrs from a running kudu-tserver instance?

Something like :

```
kudu-tserver show tserver_master_addrs
```

Answer (score 1):

The command `kudu master list` will show you the master addresses however you still need to know of one master addresses (I know, seems strange to me too).

```
$ kudu master list MASTER_HOST:RPC_PORT
```

https://kudu.apache.org/docs/command_line_tools_reference.html#master